# Apache PHP check if file exsists - what does is_file really do on the server

Tags: php, apache

In my apache logs I see a lot of:

Attempt to serve directory: somedir/
This error appears because I dont allow directory browsing.

Now I know that they appear when someone enters a page where the database thinks it have a picture and then return an empty field thus when I do:

background-image: url("somedir/{$value[self::PICTURE]}");

and there is no picture it will look at the directory insted somedir/

To avoid this I made if(is_file("somedir/{$value[self::PICTURE]}")) but I still see the errors. Now my question is what is the best approach to check if a file is present without getting an apache error log entry if the file is not there?

Comment: should not you use double quotes in if statement? if(is_file("somedir/{$value[self::PICTURE]}"))

Comment: Ye I am using " not ' ... I just typed them wrong in here :)

Comment: Are you sure you are checking the paths correctly, is your css located in your php file or is it in an external file in a different directory?

Comment: Yes the paths is correctly. This is working most of the time. Sometimes I have an irregularity between the database and the filestorage. The database have an image name but the file does not exist on the filestorage thus making the error. I just want the best way to check if the file is there without making an error log entry when asking on a file that dosent exist.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the variable you're checking for is set. 
Like :

```
if ( isset ( $file ) && file_exists ( $file ))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a PHP variable within a string, you should use double quotes instead of single ones. That may be the reason why your script fail.

```php
$path = 'somedir/' . $value[self::PICTURE];
if (is_file($path) || is_dir($path)) {
    // Your logic here
}
```

Comment: My bad... I am using " not ' ... I just typed them wrong in here :)